# Is there a Switch case in smarty?

Tags: smarty

I am working on a website using Smarty. I have searched the web to find out whether or not I can use `switch` case with Smarty. But i cannot able to find any useful links for this.

Is it possible to use Switch case in Smarty? if so how?

Comment: It definitely is possible if you install this plugin: http://pynej.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/switch-statment-for-smarty-3.html

Comment: @JohnMagnolia please add your comment as an answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find the documentation here:
http://www.smarty.net/documentation

No it's not possible (without a plugin). But you can use it in php and assign your results. Or in smarty you can use the if condition instead in a different way.

Answer (score 10):

You can also just use a simple if / elsif statement, if you don't like or can install the plugin:

```
{if $case1_as_condition}
   Case 1
{elseif $case2_as_condition}
   Case 2, etc
{else}
   Default
{/if}
```

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if

Answer (score 4):

Yes with an extra plugin: http://pynej.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/switch-statment-for-smarty-3.html

```
{switch $debugItem.type}
   {case 1}
   {case "invalid_field"}
      // Case checks for string and numbers.
   {/case}
   {case $postError}
   {case $getError|cat:"_ajax"|lower}
      // Case checks can also use variables and modifiers.
      {break}
   {default}
      // Default case is supported.
{/switch}
```